# kubeadm join failing on Pi 3 model B. cannot create certificate signing request: the server could not find the requested resource

Tags: raspberry-pi, kubernetes

I have set up a cluster of four Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and installed HypriotOS.
The master node is running fine however when I issue the join command on one of the other Pi 3 nodes it fails with the following error:

```
HypriotOS/armv7: root@black-pearl_1 in ~
$ kubeadm join --token=f5ffb9.0fefbf6e0f289a61 192.168.1.20 --skip-preflight-checks
[kubeadm] WARNING: kubeadm is in alpha, please do not use it for production clusters.
[preflight] Skipping pre-flight checks
[tokens] Validating provided token
[discovery] Created cluster info discovery client, requesting info from "http://192.168.1.20:9898/cluster-info/v1/?token-id=f5ffb9"
[discovery] Cluster info object received, verifying signature using given token
[discovery] Cluster info signature and contents are valid, will use API endpoints [https://192.168.1.20:6443]
[bootstrap] Trying to connect to endpoint https://192.168.1.20:6443
[bootstrap] Detected server version: v1.6.0
[bootstrap] Successfully established connection with endpoint "https://192.168.1.20:6443"
[csr] Created API client to obtain unique certificate for this node, generating keys and certificate signing request
failed to request signed certificate from the API server [cannot create certificate signing request: the server could not find the requested resource]
```

I have tried these solutions and neither of them work, I get the same error on any of the other three Pi nodes when running the join. [kubeadm join failing. Unable to request signed cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009758/kubeadm-join-failing-unable-to-request-signed-cert)

To replicate this just follow this set up procedure
https://blog.hypriot.com/post/setup-kubernetes-raspberry-pi-cluster/

Can anyone help with my understanding of what is going wrong and how to fix as I cannot find a solution on the Kubernetes trouble shooting?

To help by responding to Karun's the question about using the `--skip-preflight-checks` flag. When running the join command without this it simply fails with the following:

```
HypriotOS/armv7: root@black-pearl_2 in ~
$ kubeadm join --token=f5ffb9.0fefbf6e0f289a61 192.168.1.20
[kubeadm] WARNING: kubeadm is in alpha, please do not use it for production clusters.
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] The system verification failed. Printing the output from the verification:
OS: Linux
KERNEL_VERSION: 4.4.50-hypriotos-v7+
CONFIG_NAMESPACES: enabled
CONFIG_NET_NS: enabled
CONFIG_PID_NS: enabled
CONFIG_IPC_NS: enabled
CONFIG_UTS_NS: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUPS: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER: enabled
CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED: enabled
CONFIG_CPUSETS: enabled
CONFIG_MEMCG: enabled
CONFIG_INET: enabled
CONFIG_EXT4_FS: enabled
CONFIG_PROC_FS: enabled
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_REDIRECT: enabled (as module)
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT: enabled (as module)
CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS: enabled (as module)
CONFIG_AUFS_FS: not set - Required for aufs.
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM: enabled (as module)
CGROUPS_CPU: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUACCT: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUSET: enabled
CGROUPS_DEVICES: enabled
CGROUPS_FREEZER: enabled
CGROUPS_MEMORY: enabled
DOCKER_VERSION: 17.03.0-ce
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    unsupported docker version: 17.03.0-ce
    hostname "black-pearl_2" must match the regex [a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)* (e.g. 'example.com')
    Port 10250 is in use
    /etc/kubernetes/manifests is not empty
    /var/lib/kubelet is not empty
    /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf already exists
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can skip pre-flight checks with `--skip-preflight-checks`
```

The `--skip-preflight-checks` flag was also required to get the master node running. I therefore assume this issue must be arm specific as the solution to copy

```
/etc/kubernetes/*
```

from the master also fails to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you are passing --skip-preflight-checks as a flag in your kubeadm join command? Anything failing there? May be that can lead to some clues.

I have not worked on Raspberry, but I faced this sort of an issue on Ubuntu env. For some reason on slave node ('am firing kubeadm join command) /etc/kubernetes folder wasn't there. I just copied from master node contents of /etc/kubernetes/* into slave nodes at same location /etc/kubernetes.

After this run kubeadm join with --skip-preflight-checks explicity.

This time kubeadm got the required resources and